# Undefined useRef issue with NextJS 13 Pages router and react library built with Parcel

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13, parceljs

I have a React component library built with parcel@2.10, which throws this when using with nextjs 13/14, just pages router, not even with app router.

The error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
```

Which means the `react` variable from `import * as React from 'react'` is undefined as I understand it.

I created a minimal reproduction of the issue:

Nextjs App:
https://github.com/yyyyaaa/reproduction-next-parcel-pages-bug

Library:
https://github.com/yyyyaaa/my-react-lib

Reproduction steps:

- Clone both repo, run `npm install` in both repo
- in library folder, run `npm link && npm run build`. This creates an npm link and build the library.
- in next app folder, `run npm link "my-react-lib"`, this linked the local library code. Then npm run dev , you'll see the error.